# When did color-coding NM-B cable become standard in the US?

Tags: electrical, wiring, nec

Wandering through the electrical aisle of my local big-box store, I see that it is now basically impossible to buy NM-B cable that doesn't adhere to this color coding:

- 14 AWG = white jacket
- 12 AWG = yellow jacket
- 10 AWG = orange jacket

I understand the color coding, and it makes a *lot* of sense (I've got a mixture of 12 & 14AWG NM-B in my house and I really wish it was that easy to identify which was which when looking in a box). My question is two-fold:

1. *When* did this become standard (in the US)?
2. Is it an NEC *requirement*, or is it just a "standard" or "new tradition"?

Comment: Interestingly, I've now noted that at least one local retailer 12/3 is purple and 14/3 is light blue. I've not noted this at other retailers yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type NM-B cable first began to be manufactured with color-coded jackets in 2001 to aid in identification of the conductor size. The color code that was introduced, which continues to be used today is as follows:

- 14 AWG – White
- 12 AWG – Yellow
- 10 AWG – Orange
- 8 AWG – Black
- 6 AWG – Black​

This color coding system was developed to aid those who sell, install, and inspect Type NM-B cable so that the cable size can easily be identified, to reduce mistakes resulting from the use of an incorrect conductor size.

Comment: Is it an NEC _requirement_ or is it simply _convention_?

Comment: Also, are both #8 & #6 black or was that a typo?

Comment: 6&8 are both black the only addition would be for UF it is gray. It is not a requirement but was done to make it easier to see what your inventory is.

Comment: @FreeMan -- it is conventional, for the reason Ed says.  (UF is always grey, best I can tell)